# calculate percentage/repartition of values with a sql query

Tags: sql

I have the following table

| type | color | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | white | true |
| B | black | false |
| c | yellow | true |
| d | red | true |
| f | green | false |

and I want to calculate with a sql query the percentage of rows having value equal to true , here for example we have 3 trues over a total of 5 lines which makes a percentage of 60% of types having a value equal to true , any idea how to fix this please ?

Comment: Which dialect or RDBMS?  SQL Server, MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8, SQLite, Oracle, SAS Proc SQL, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want a single value to be returned?

Depending on which RDBMS you're using boolean values are handled differently, but the basic structure should be similar to...

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN value = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM
  yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when value = 'true' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from t;
```

This returns the ratio, between 0 and 1.  If you want a percentage between 0 and 100, then use `100.0` instead of `1.0`.